# Standard searchable term for "in person" (of a meeting)

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, if I were to search Google for support groups and wanted to filter out everything that wasn't in person, what word is my best choice?

The words "in" and "person" are individually too vague, so combined as a multiple word symbol seems less efficient as an <strike>identifiable category of meaning</strike> attribute.

<sub>This should be an adjective, replacing "in-person".</sub>
<sub><sub>Probably a more accurate question would be what to do when you feel you're using an attribute that doesn't belong. Which is the case here. It's a reasoning problem not a language one. The category of adjective needs to change. Perhaps to a locale attribute, which would imply in-person.</sub></sub>

Comment: Try using a hyphen: _an in-person meeting_.

Comment: you might also look for *face-to-face* meetings

Comment: Or simply "meetup"